# Custom Menu Item is Disabled

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I'm creating a Cocoa app in `XCode`. I have quite a few menu items, but some Mac apps have notably more than mine. All of them work except one, which is disabled, even though I didn't change the *enabled* option. I tried deleting it and re-adding it, changing the key equivalent, but it's still disabled.

Is there a limit to the number of menu items I can have?

Comment: There is no limit. What is the menu item's action? My first guess would be that `NSMenuValidation` is causing the item to be disabled.

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000261-BAJBFGED

Comment: That's strange. For some reason it works now. Just to clarify, will the menu be disabled if I don't link it to a method in my source code? That might have been the issue.

Comment: possibly, it wouldn't make sense to enable a menu item which is unable to perform an action.